# Scrolling does not minify iphone browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, css

I searched all over but can't find a solution. I have a mobile website using a container div (width and height 100%). I use -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; to make the content in div smooth scrolling.

However, normally when you scroll down in an iphone your addressbar will shrink and the controls at the bottom totally disappear. Because of the container div having the same size as the body the phone does not detect scrolling in the body. And therefor it will not optimize screen availability.
Does anyone know a good workaround?

I fiddled with BRIM and other JS solutions but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance.